# How to create an array of a class containing objects as array elements?

Tags: java, arrays

I want to create a program containing a class Accounts with id, username, balance as data items and a constructor that takes entry.Now from another class AccountDemo, I want to enter 10 user details containing the previous data items.so do I have to make 10 separate objects of class Accounts? I want to use a loop for the entry but cannot find a correct syntax.

Comment: You can do it. What stopping you?

Comment: `Accounts accounts = new Accounts[arraySize];` to initialise array an then `accounts[index] = new Accounts();` inside the loop

Comment: Won't I have to create 10 objects for 10 users? Thats the array of 1 object..

Comment: @Germann Arlington: Are you missing `[]` after `Accounts` or `accounts`?

Comment: This is what I had done   //Initialising array of objects
  Accounts[] user= new Accounts[10];
  
  //for user input of Account details
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
   System.out.print("\n");
   user[i]= new Accounts();
   
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create array of object of `Account` class. [see here](http://www.javawithus.com/tutorial/array-of-objects)..

**UPDATE:**

> Sorting happens perfectly but during display, username with highest
>   balance is not displayed correctly.. I mean highest balance with the
>   username of array [0] is displayed.

You're just swapping the balance instead you need to swap the entire `Account` object,so your `for-loop` code must be

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < 9; j++) {
                if (user[i].balance < user[j].balance) {
                    Account temp = user[i];
                    user[i] = user[j];
                    user[j]= temp;
                }
            }
        }
```

Also value of `j` must be `0<=j<9` since you're initializing `j` at `i+1`

Comment: Thanks.. I have also taken reference from this site. Everything works well, but the problem arises if I try to sort the array according to balance. Sorting happens perfectly but during display, username with highest balance is not displayed correctly.. I mean highest balance with the username of array [0] is displayed.so the 2 variables are not linked together. I dont know if I am making sense....

Comment: Can you add your sorting method to your question?

Comment: case 3:  for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
           for(int j=i+1;j<10;j++){
         if(user[i].balance < user[j].balance){
          double temp=user[i].balance;
          user[i].balance= user[j].balance;
          user[j].balance= temp;
           }
       }
       } 
       for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
                user[i].show();
                   }
                         break;

Comment: void show(){
   
   System.out.println("\n Id: "+id+ "\n Name: "+name+ "\n Balance: "+balance);
   
  }

Comment: @Kainix thanks that was very helpful. One edit needs to be made. The j loop should end at 10        for (int j = i + 1; j < 10; j++) {

Comment: @Tani.c as you say, try doing it. 
It will give you `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: Have done it. No problem.. otherwise the last entry wouldn't be sorted.